# Postman - how to target the final iteration?

Tags: postman, postman-collection-runner

I would like to run a Postman test on just the *final* iteration of a test run - I am building a variable (array) of response time values across all of the iterations and then want to test this variable for extreme values once we've reached the last / final iteration.

I hoped `pm.info.iteration` would have my answer but didn't see anything relevant.

I'm using a data file - the test runner highlights how many iterations are applicable (rows in the csv) as soon as the file is chosen so I'm guessing that Postman does know 'final' iteration? I just haven't worked out how to get at it.

My workaround is to hard code the number of iterations per test run based on how many rows my csvs currently have (e.g. `if(pm.iteration.info === 70)` but not ideal as the data file is likely to grow.

Comment: Wouldn't `(pm.info.iteration === pm.info.iterationCount)` make that more dynamic?

Comment: Thanks @DannyDainton - why oh why did I think i couldn't find this?! I'm going crazy. Hope you are well :)

Comment: No worries - Please accept @PDHide's answer as that looks like what you need.

Answer (score 4):

As @DannyDainton mentioned you can use iterationCOunt

iteration index starts from 0 ,so use

`(pm.info.iteration === (pm.info.iterationCount-1) )`